# Combine Multiple workbooks to one master workbook in excel 2013

Tags: vba, excel

The code listed below is working for me to combine multiple workbook sheet1 (specific cell range) to the master sheet . But i'm facing one issue that is the  paste special option is not working

**For eg:** My cells contains background color indication like amber, green and font color in each cells are different .I'm getting the output as plain text instead of rich text. If I try to modify the code with Pastespecial it's not working .

Can someone help me to fix this ?

```
Sub LoopThroughDirectory()      
Dim MyFile As String       
Dim erow       
Dim Filepath As String       
Filepath = "Paste your path    
MyFile = Dir(Filepath)   
Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
If MyFile = "zmaster.xlsm" Then  
End If

Workbooks.Open (Filepath & MyFile)
Range("A2:G2").Copy
ActiveWorkbook.Close

erow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(erow, 1), Cells(erow, 7))

MyFile = Dir
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: `activesheet.past` should work fine. Instead of Closing the active sheet try to make the destination sheet active before pasting it

Comment: Close the workbook after pasting. Your code could be tidied up - add workbook/sheet references - and what is that If statement doing?

Comment: @Praveen,That didn't help .

Comment: @SJR-If statement is to pull all the excel sheets.Based on the code the one with the extension macros will be ignored in that particular folder since all the files are stored in the same location

Comment: Most of them are telling that the range.pastespecial will work but if I modify the above code it's not working. Can you please help me ?

Comment: @KrishnaPriya you want to copy and past with all formatting as its is in source file..

Comment: @PraveenRKaruppannan,yes